# C++ pass 3D array by reference to second object, can't manipulate

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glut

As the title states, I am attempting to manipulate a 3D array in the object of an object. Both objects have the exact same function declaration, yet only the parent object is capable of manipulating the array (turning the frame buffer white). The 3D array that I am attempting to manipulate is contained within the scope of the main. The 3D array has no issues being manipulated by the parent object, however when passed to the child of the parent object nothing changes.

I pass a the frame buffer (3D array) from the main to the polygon manager, where I am able to make the frame buffer white by setting all the values to 1.0. However, even when I have numerous polygons and points in my system after several clicks, I am unable to further pass the frame buffer to the polygon object contained within the polygon manager. I comment out the "white-out" for loop in the polygon manager and attempt to use it again in polygon. Nothing happens.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include "polygon_manager.h"

#define ImageW 400
#define ImageH 400

float framebuffer[ImageH][ImageW][3];

PolygonManager polygon_manager;

// Draws the scene
void drawit( void ) {
    glDrawPixels( ImageW, ImageH, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, framebuffer );
    glFlush();
}

// Clears framebuffer to black
void clearFramebuffer() {
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < ImageH; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < ImageW; j++ ) {
            framebuffer[i][j][0] = 0.0;
            framebuffer[i][j][1] = 0.0;
            framebuffer[i][j][2] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

void display( void ) {
    /** THIS IS WHERE I AM MODIFYING THE BUFFER */
    polygon_manager.add_points( framebuffer );

    drawit();
}

void onMouse( int button, int state, int x, int y ) {
    if ( state == GLUT_DOWN ) {
        if ( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON ) {
            polygon_manager.add_point( x, y );
        }

        if ( button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON ) {
            polygon_manager.add_final_point( x, y );
        }
        cout << polygon_manager;
    }
}

void init( void ) {
    clearFramebuffer();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( ImageW, ImageH );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Robert Timm - Homework 3" );
    init();
    glutMouseFunc( onMouse );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**polygon_manager.h**

```
#ifndef POLYGON_MANAGER_H_
#define POLYGON_MANAGER_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "point.h"
#include "color.h"
#include "polygon.h"

const int MAX_POLYGONS = 10;

using namespace std;

class PolygonManager {

public:

    PolygonManager() {
        create_new_poly = true;
    }

    void add_point( int x, int y ) {
        if ( create_new_poly ) {
            if ( polygons.size() >= MAX_POLYGONS ) {
                cerr << "Max number of polygons added (" << MAX_POLYGONS << ")"
                        << endl;
                return;
            }
            create_new_poly = false;
            Polygon p;
            polygons.push_back( p );
        }
        polygons.back().add_point( x, y );
    }

    void add_final_point( int x, int y ) {
        if ( polygons.back().size() < 2 ) {
            cerr << "Polygon requires at least three points "
                    << "to be considered a polygon!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        if ( create_new_poly ) {
            cerr << "Right-click already pressed. Left click "
                    << "to add a new polygon." << endl;
            return;
        }
        create_new_poly = true;
        polygons.back().add_point( x, y );
    }

    void add_points( float (&framebuffer)[400][400][3] ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < polygons.size(); ++i ) {
            polygons[i].add_points( framebuffer );
        }
        /** EDITING BUFFER HERE CHANGES SCREEN FROM BLACK TO WHITE
             AS INTENDED */
        for ( int i = 0; i < 400; ++i ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 400; ++j ) {
                framebuffer[j][i][0] = 1.0;
                framebuffer[j][i][1] = 1.0;
                framebuffer[j][i][2] = 1.0;
            }
        }

    }

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const PolygonManager& pm ) {
        os << "Polygons:" << endl;
        for ( auto &polygon : pm.polygons ) {
            os << "=> " << polygon << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }

private:

    bool create_new_poly;
    vector<Polygon> polygons;

};

#endif
```

**polygon.h**

```
#ifndef POLYGON_H_
#define POLYGON_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include "color.h"
#include "point.h"

const int MAX_POINTS = 10;

using namespace std;

class Polygon {

public:
    Polygon() {

    }

    int size() {
        return points.size();
    }

    void add_point( int x, int y ) {
        if ( points.size() >= (MAX_POINTS - 1) ) {
            cerr << "This polygon already has nine points, add a final "
                    << "tenth point by right-clicking the screen." << endl;
            return;
        }
        Point p( x, y );
        points.push_back( p );
    }

    void add_final_point( int x, int y ) {
        Point p( x, y );
        points.push_back( p );
    }

    void add_points( float (&framebuffer)[400][400][3] ) {
        for ( auto &point : points ) {
            int y = 400 - 1 - point.get_y();
            int x = point.get_x();
        }
        /** EDITING BUFFER HERE DOES NOTHING, SCREEN
         *  SHOULD TURN WHITE
         */
        for ( int i = 0; i < 400; ++i ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 400; ++j ) {
                framebuffer[j][i][0] = 1.0;
                framebuffer[j][i][1] = 1.0;
                framebuffer[j][i][2] = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const Polygon& poly ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < poly.points.size(); ++i ) {
            if ( i < poly.points.size() - 1 ) {
                os << poly.points[i] << ", ";
            } else {
                os << poly.points[i];
            }
        }
        return os;
    }

private:
    Color color;
    vector<Point> points;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that compiles and runs?

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B27STV_TwIfeUVJvZ1NsWFhHam8&authuser=0

Comment: You must include it inside the question.

Comment: Require additional pylons too?

Comment: Moved the code to the question @NeilKirk

Comment: Do not put images of source here. Instead, you should paste the relevant source here.

Comment: This is the sort of thing where I would just wrap the array into an object and pass the object reference.  Or better yet just have the `add_points()` function to be a method of the 3D array class as well.

Comment: We do not know what these parent objects and child objects are, and we do not know how you detect that nothing changes.  So, we need to see more code.  The code should be inside the question, and preferably as text, rather than as image.

Comment: Updated original question with source and refined question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polygon manager was editing the frame buffer but only once. I had a misunderstanding with the registered callback in Main.cpp "display". Originally I had thought that display would be called numerous times when it was actually only being called once when the application opened. I added,

```
glutPostRedisplay();
```

To the end of my **onMouse** callback to let the display know the frame buffer needed updated. This allowed the polygon manager to traverse to each polygon and turn the screen white. In future iterations whiting out the screen will be replaced with a polygon drawing algorithm.

Comment: Since the problem was a defect in your code making this more of a debugging problem than a question that fits the format of stackoverflow perhaps this question should be deleted?

Comment: Why is this site so heavily moderated now? No, please don't delete this I know a couple hundred students at my university alone learning OpenGL alongside me. This could be helpful for them.

Comment: This site is more heavily moderated now due to the general increase of questions from people who do not appear to have taken the time to do basic research and review on their questions before submitting a question. The greatly increased level of poor questions has in turn flooded the site with a lot of noise.  **What about this question and the answer makes you think it may be helpful to other people?**  Normally if people find a question helpful or think it may be helpful to others, positive votes are used to indicate this.  Why would this question show in a search for this problem?

Comment: Richard, I'm not going to get in an argument. I've already had one person tell me this question helped them today in class. Try and have more patience for young students, especially those who are excited about contributing to this amazing resource.